# Could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (2)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wont create a matrix of matrix with numpy.array, this matrix only need two elements, the comand is:

```
numpy.array([m1,m2])
```

this work fine indpendently of the matrices size, except when a matrix have a dimension in one.
Example:

```
m1 = numpy.ones((2,2))
m2 = numpy.ones((2,1))
numpy.array([m1,m2])
```

In this case show error... and the shape for the matrices are (2,2) and (2,1) but for some reason i think that the dimension 1 is the problem.
Someone know as fix this problem. Thanks!

Comment: The arrays differ in size, so it can't make a neat 3d array.  If the arrays differ in the first dimension it can make a (2,) shape object dtype array.   But with the same 1st dimension, `np.array` throws an error.  Maybe you shouldn't be creating such an array!

Comment: What exactly are you expecting?  Can you get there without using `np.array`?  Remember, an object dtype array is little better than a list, and in some ways, worse.

Comment: Another way to phrase this - `np.array([m1,m2])` is an unreliable way of making a (2,) shape object dtype array.  Better `M=np.empty(2, object)` and `M[0]=m1` and `M[1]=m2` (or some variation on that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a known bug, or maybe just an undesirable behavior in numpy.


https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7453


I would definitely question why this particular arrangement is appealing, though. 

Obv not for the matrix arithmetic operations, since your arrays are of varying *nth*-dimension.